# What is the Hoor/Houris concept?

Tags: houri

Assalamo alaikum, this hoor thing has broken me to the depth that i can't explain I've many questions related to it. I don't want any male hoor anything.

1. Are women(wordly) described as hoor when they'll be recreated or something?
2. Is it 'must' to have hoors in jannah? Can't they be rejected?
3. Will prophets also have hoors?
4. As said there'll be no nafs in jannah then one can have physical relationships as in intercourse with hoors?
5. Why women have to share their husband and brainwashed that no jealousy or anything and this way we'll accept hoors.
6. If women in jannah is already more beautiful and all then why would men go to hoors?
7. If we're able to have wives anf husband in jannah from the world then why do they need hoors?

As it it said they're given because men and women build differently the have desires and because they control it in here Allah SWT will give them in jannah as their reward. We're also human we also desires if we don't show or something doesn't that make us we've less desire than them or something I've read somewhere that because women spend more time in beautifying themselves and men are more attracted towards these thing you know what i mean so indeed Allah is most just so Allah has made hoors for men and beautified women in jannah.

Few questions, please answer. Help me.

Jazakumallahu khairan kaseeran.

Answer (score 0):

Most questions can be answered based on this verse:

> نَحۡنُ أَوۡلِيَآؤُكُمۡ فِي ٱلۡحَيَوٰةِ ٱلدُّنۡيَا وَفِي ٱلۡأٓخِرَةِۖ
> وَلَكُمۡ فِيهَا مَا تَشۡتَهِيٓ أَنفُسُكُمۡ وَلَكُمۡ فِيهَا مَا
> تَدَّعُونَ 31
>
> We are your friends in this life and in the Hereafter where you will get whatever your Nafs desire, and have whatsoever you ask for  [31](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/41/31/)

In heaven, everything is based on your desires.

1 Hooris are different from humans. women in heaven are much more beautiful than the hooris.

2 "There is no "must" in heaven. There, whatever you desire. Must is for this world.

3 if they desire.

4 This is wrong. The above verse is stating that humans have "nafs" in heaven.

5 There is no "have to."

6 perhaps they desire.

7 Perhaps they desire. If a woman has one piece of clothing, why does she need more?

Answer (score -1):

Hoors are not human, may be. They are special creation who look like human albeit more sacred and beautiful. Now, when people will be in Jannah, they will have no need to urinate, defecate, menstruation, disease and all these problems that we face in the world, will be completely erased. So when a woman goes to Jannah, she basically becomes like the hoors; not actual hoor, but in characteristics become like a hoor. Hoors dont have to go through worldly test, they are already in akhirat for the people who will go to jannah. But human beings have to pass through the test of the world and then only they can stay in jannah. Thats the difference.

In quran and hadis, there are not a lot of explanation about them. But I will tell you as far as I know.

1. We dont know for sure whether worldly women will be promoted as hoors or hoors are totally different creation than humans. Both way it does not matter once you get jannat. Because in Jannat even if there is no hoors, your wishful thinking will be enough to provide you whatever you want.
2. There is no rules in Jannah. Rules are for testing humans in the world not in akhirat. So whether you want any hoor or not are totally personal matter.
3. Depends on prophets. If they want, surely they will get.
4. Yes hoors will be like wives. So no problem. Nafs? Ok, nafs is the desire of people for haram things. In jannat there will be no haram things.
5. Who told you to brainwash women? The one who said it is definitely a wicked person at heart. Allah already told us there will be no clash or dissatisfaction in jannat. Men will get hoors. Women will get whatever they want. So what if their desire contradict each other? Bro, this is jannat we are talking about. Allah will settle down everything as promised. So why bother thinking with the problem of human beings?  You know we dont have any capacity to solve anything for humanity and you also know Allah promised to solve everything. So have some faith in Allah? Curious to know how it will happen? Wait for it until you enter to jannah. Alternatively keep dreaming and waste your time.
6. Why people will demand hoor when they have their wives? Well, ask yourself when you go to jannah. Psychology is a complex matter. We can not know every human psychology 100% if we dont experience ourselves. With so less resources of the world, we yet dont know worldly psychology and in akhirat when you will have infinite amount of resources and you will have demand based on that infinite possibilities, how can you know what will happen in future of the akhirat staying in this mundane triffling earth? Again waste of time thinking what we dont know.
7. Same question asked differently. So read the same answer again and you will understand.

Overall curiocity is good. But realizing environmental factors and  situation are more important. We definitely dont have all the answer. But if we had all the answers, there will be no room for surprise in the akhirat, right? The fruit of patience is always damn good. Bro, if you love your wife that much; take care of her and stay in the right path of Allah. This is all we can do in our dunya. Whoever has faith in Allah, he will get what he deserves, even if it is not in this world.

Forgive me for my straight impolite answer. May Allah give us blessing and victory in the duniya and Akhirat...